# SVG <use> elements in Chrome not displayed

Tags: google-chrome, svg

Chrome seems not to display `<use>` elements in inline svg. Here is an example (code below or view it at http://www.bobwyttenbach.com/chromeuse.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Chrome use-tag bug?</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
        <g id="test1">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="red"/>
        </g>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="199" height="199" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
        <use xlink:href="#test1" x="0" y="0"/>
    </g>
</svg>
<p>Above is inline svg with a use tag; below is the same svg linked through an object tag. Below is correct.</p>
<object data="chromeuse.svg" width="200" height="200"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

The red circle does not appear in the inline svg but does appear when the same svg is linked through an object tag. Safari, Firefox, Opera, and Internet Explorer 9 all display the inline svg correctly.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known Chrome bug (I haven't found it listed)? Any workarounds?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, report to webkit here: http://bugs.webkit.org

Comment: @ErikDahlström Rats, I had hoped you would have a work-around.
Reported to webkit.org (ID=91498) and to code.google.com (Issue 137666), since this is specifically a Chrome bug that does not appear in Safari.

Comment: And this is what I got back from chromium@googlecode.com:

Comment #2 on issue 137666 by pdr@chromium.org:  SVG <use> elements not displayed in Chrome (Safari is OK)
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137666

This was fixed with the self-closing use tag change: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/118589

Due to the severity of this break, the fix has been merged into Chrome 20: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/122596

We plan to push this in the next Chrome 20 update, probably next week. Apologies for the break, but the good news is a fix is imminent :)

Comment: Update: fixed in today's version of Chrome (21.0.1180.57), which uses WebKit 537.1. Newly broken in yesterday's version of Safari (6), which uses WebKit 536.25.

Comment: looks like they broke it again.. :\

Comment: the problem still exists in the Chrome 36.0.1985.143 version. Is there any alternate solution for this problem?

Comment: Apparently this is a security "feature" now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this question is still relevant, but I've met such a case recently and I pretty sure that somebody else will meet the case (especially those who tries to make use of SVG sprites for the first time).

In my case I've joined 16 SVG icons in one sprite manually into `sprite.svg`, and in this file I've omitted important meta information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

I had no first line at all, and all I had on the second line was an opening `<svg>` tag with no meta attributes (`xmlns` and `xmlns:xlink`). As soon as I brought back all this omitted meta information, my graphics from `sprite.svg` started to display properly.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I deleted my last post as I incorrectly tried to figure out why the use element was working for me and not for you. What I can say is that I am using a modified version of this source, https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/ , so in short, my answer is to walk through and see how they do it. I believe its demonstrated when you insert an image from their library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into that further. It's pretty convoluted at first look. I can get a use element to show in the svg-edit workspace, but once I copy the code out into my own html, it stops working. Maybe I can track down the right combination of things (they have svg inside svg, etc.).

Comment: It's a verified Chrome bug that should be fixed in the next release (see above). I also discovered a workaround. Instead of `<use xlink:whatever.../>` one can say `<use xlink:whatever...></use>`. In my tests, that worked, though I'll probably just ignore it and wait for the next release of Chrome.

Comment: are you sure that it isn't that the xml for svg doesn't specify that use can be ended with /> ?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time debugging inline svg use elements not showing up.  The chrome bug discussed by BobW seems fixed at this time.  To eliminate the same issue caused by something else entirely, try commenting out the `<base href="somethingsomethingsomething" />` tag from your HTML.

Of course, this will likely break every relative link on your site, but the `<use>` elements now show up.  One step forward, half a step back :)

Related info here:
[Using base tag on a page that contains SVG marker elements fails to render marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259032/using-base-tag-on-a-page-that-contains-svg-marker-elements-fails-to-render-marke)