# Does element order matter for inline SVG?

Tags: google-chrome, svg

In Google Chrome 24, if an element referenced by a `<use>` element is defined later in the document it isn't rendered.  I didn't notice anything related to element order in the documentation for the [`use`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) element.

Is this behavior undefined and shouldn't be expected to be consistent across browsers or just a bug in Chrome?

An example of this can be seen below (slightly modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514248/svg-use-elements-in-chrome-not-displayed) question).  Blue circle renders as expected, red, not so much.  Firefox 17 and IE 9 render both circles as I would expect.  When the same content is referenced as an external `<img />`, both circles render as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chrome use-tag bug?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <defs>
            <g id="test2">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="blue"/>
            </g>
        </defs>

        <g>
            <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="199" height="199" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
            <use xlink:href="#test1" x="0" y="0"/>
            <use xlink:href="#test2" x="0" y="0"/>
        </g>

        <defs>
            <g id="test1">
                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="25" fill="red"/>
            </g>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE**: Seems to be working in Chrome 39.

Comment: _i think_, order is important, at least spec says that - http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/render.html#RenderingOrder - so you have, _probably_, run into yet another webkit bug.

Comment: For painting, you're absolutely right, they do.  In this case I'm just referencing another element (that won't actually be painted).  Not sure if you have to declare elements before you can use them (like old school compilers where you can only call functions you've declared).

Comment: I agree with you, this must be a bug. The `xlink:href` referencing mechanism sadly has some flaws in Webkit.

Comment: You could post it to: bugs.webkit.org, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list in case you really think it is a bug. I did the same for another SVG related problem and they assigned the bug to a developer.

Comment: @Matthias Yep, I know, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything before I filed a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rendering Order depends on the element order, so it looks strong like a bug in chrome:
[SVG Rendering Order 1.0, Part 2: Language](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/renderorder/SVGRenderOrder.html)