# SVG straight path with clip-path not visible in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, d3.js, render

I believe that I've found a bug in Chrome's SVG rendering however I'd like to know if there are any workarounds.

With code like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <path clip-path="url(#clip)" d="M 0,100 H 1000 V 100" style="stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px"></path>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
          <rect width="400" height="400"></rect>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

[View in browser](https://rawgithub.com/mnorrish/7249967/raw/21b76b680cde35e25c98dbc57086773ea72fa02c/SVGclipPathTest.html)

There should be a 1000px long horizontal line (`path`) clipped by a 400px × 400px `rect`.

The line is visible and correctly clipped in Firefox and Internet Explorer (10) but it is completely invisible in Chrome.
There problem only exists if the `path` is completely horizontal or vertical as shown in [this example](https://rawgithub.com/mnorrish/7249967/raw/e00194669cd68cd2839d52c89c0caa4114d299c1/SVGclipPathTest.html).

It is a requirement that the `d` attribute of the `path` is an equivelent which D3.js can generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a Chrome bug.  If you reverse the order of `<defs>` and the `<path>` element, then it works.  This is basically the [same issue as with the `<use>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060337/does-element-order-matter-for-inline-svg).

Comment: That's great and tidier than my solution – thank you

Answer (score 5):

A workaround which I've made work adds an extra `moveto` command to the beginning of the `d` attribute:

```
<path clip-path="url(#clip)" d="M -10,-10 M 0,100 H 1000 V 100" style="stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px"></path>
```

[View in browser](https://rawgithub.com/mnorrish/7249967/raw/94d5a2babec7214108540735456ef8c6a6808da7/SVGclipPathTest.html)

The extra `moveto` has no visible effect but means that the `path` is not technically straight. It is visible and clipped correctly in Chrome.

Comment: ?? That's weird...  So there is something else to it in addition to the order.

Comment: Perhaps there is something more to it. I found that with `defs` after the `paths` any completely horizontal (and maybe vetical) `paths` are visible.

Comment: it's great how this is still a bug over 5 years later, but thank you for the workaround!  also worth noting that this bug is also present when using `mask`'s and not just `clipPath`s