# jQM single page app ignores SVG markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, svg, marker

I´ve got a problem combining SVG elements and jQM single page applications.
Starting on my first page of the jQM single page application (index.html), I can draw an arrow with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryMobile/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--MainPage-->
    <div data-role="page" id="Index">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             version="1.1"
             width="90%"
             style="margin: 1em;"
             viewBox="0 0 100 100"
             preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
        <defs>
        <marker id="MyMarker" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6"
                orient="auto">
            <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: black;" />
        </marker>
        </defs>

        <line x1="5" y1="5" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" style="marker-end: url(#MyMarker);"/>

        </svg>

    </div>
</body>
```

The user can navigate to another page (anotherpage.html) by: `$.mobile.changePage("content/anotherpage.html", { transition: "flow",
                changeHash: false });`

anotherpage.html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="AnotherPage">    
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 version="1.1"
                 width="90%"
                 style="margin: 1em;"
                 viewBox="0 0 100 100"
                 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
            <defs>
            <marker id="MyMarker2" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6"
                    orient="auto">
                <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: black;" />
            </marker>
            </defs>

            <line x1="5" y1="5" x2="10" y2="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" style="marker-end: url(#MyMarker2);"/>

            </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Opening the page directly shows the arrow as expected.

But after navigating from index.html to this page the marker of the svg is not displayed and I don´t know why. I tested all kind of different combinations and SVG marker examples I found but it seems that by navigating via jQM to the second page markers a generally ignored.

I found this link about [Using base tag on a page that contains...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259032/using-base-tag-on-a-page-that-contains-svg-marker-elements-fails-to-render-marke).
Tried the following with no success:

```
<line x1='5' y1='5' x2='20' y2='20' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' style='marker-end: url(#MyMarker2);'/>
<line x1='5' y1='5' x2='30' y2='20' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' style='marker-end: url(Test_de.html#MyMarker2);'/>
<line x1='5' y1='5' x2='20' y2='30' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' style='marker-end: url(content/Test_de.html#MyMarker2);'/>
<line x1='5' y1='5' x2='10' y2='20' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' style='marker-end: url(./content/Test_de.html#MyMarker2);'/>
```

Also tried adding the marker programmatically with full path.

Tested it on Chrome. It always says marker-end is none on the computed properties listed in the developer tools.

I hope someone can help. Thank you.

**Edit:**

Sorry. Solved the problem by myself. Problem was the option "changeHash: false" for the page transition.