# Why snapsvg mask doesn't work in Chrome and Firefox when there's a <base> tag in the header?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, svg, snap.svg

Here is my code

```
    var s = Snap("#mySVG");
    var r = s.rect(0,0,100,200,20,20).attr({ stroke: '#FFFFFF', 'strokeWidth': 20, fill: 'red' });
    var clip1 = s.rect(0,0,200,60).attr({ stroke: '#FFFFFF', 'strokeWidth': 1, fill: 'white' });
    r.attr({ mask: clip1 });
```

The mask works as expected in IE 10 but not in Firefox 32 and Chrome 37.

What is wrong ?

EDIT 
After user13500 answer. I turned the problem around, started with a blank page and import all elements from my non working page. It appears that a base tag in the header prevent it to work under FF and Chrome. That's looks crazy to me as everything else but masks works, so it's not a script path problem.

```
 <base href="http://127.0.0.1/mySiteDev/">
```

Comment: It works as I expect on Firefox 32. I.e. it displays the top of a rounded rect cut off at the bottom by the mask. What are you seeing and what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as commented by [@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson), the masks url change with the base tag. You can reproduce the sample by plain HTML/SVG as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Snap base</title>
<style media="screen">
body {
        background: #fff;
}
</style>
<base href="http://127.0.0.1/mySiteDev/">
</head>
<body>
<svg id="mySVG">
<defs>
    <mask id="Si0fh161e4">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="60" stroke="#ffffff" 
              style="stroke-width: 1px;" fill="#ffffff">
        </rect>
    </mask>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200" rx="20" ry="20" stroke="#ffffff" 
      fill="#ff0000" style="stroke-width: 20px;" mask="url('#Si0fh161e4')">
<!--                                       Problem URL --^              -->
</rect>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the url `url('#Si0fh161e4')` uses `http://127.0.0.1/mySiteDev/`, to correct it one have to include document. E.g.

```
mask="url('the_document.html#Si0fh161e4')"></rect>
```

or, the somewhat useless;

```
<base href="//127.0.0.1/mySiteDev/the_document.html">
<base href="the_document.html">
...
```

which defeats the usability

I have not found anything in the Snap documentation on setting base for URLs, but I'll look further.

---

### *Old answer:*

Your code works fine here. Chrome 37, Firefox 32, Opera 12.

Result:

[image]

---

Sample snippet, (your code):

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var s = Snap("#mySVG");
    var r = s.rect(0, 0, 100, 200, 20, 20).attr({ 
        stroke      : '#FFFFFF', 
        strokeWidth : 20, 
        fill        : 'red' 
    });
    var clip1 = s.rect(0, 0, 200, 60).attr({ 
        stroke      : '#FFFFFF', 
        strokeWidth : 1, 
        fill        : 'white' 
    });
    r.attr({ 
        mask: clip1 
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySVG"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying it ! Can you please try with <base href="http://127.0.0.1/mySiteDev/"> in the headers ? 5I edited the question)

Comment: The base tag makes the mask url change. I'm still not totally sure whether that's the right thing to do. The SVG spec says it should not but it may be in conflict with other specifications.

Comment: This should be documented and it is strange it works on IE. Snap should care of it. I report an issue.

Comment: @bokan: There might be some follow ups here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snapsvg/ri9tYdjVG9Y ... I can delete it, (if possible), if you wan't to post your own.

Comment: @bokan: Also, if I read this correctly, I do not have any IE 10 to test on at the moment, using absolute URI on IE makes it fail. So one have to do a old ugly browser test ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259032/using-base-tag-on-a-page-that-contains-svg-marker-elements-fails-to-render-marke#comment26801522_18265336 Real fun. In other words, if at all possible, try to get rid of `<base>`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this mask url() issue in AngularJS template which contained similar svg structure like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RopoMen/5qdnjme0/). That worked fine until I noticed that it wasn't working in "search" page. I finally found this Stackoverflow thread and did some extra research, in my site base tag is always something like this

```
 <base href="/en/search/">
```

when you are in url "http ://example.com/en/search/?q=something"

In my AngularJS template I had to add "{{path}}" in to mask url. (check that fiddle for full svg)

```
<rect x="0" y="0"  width="48" height="47" fill="#008FDB" mask="url({{path}}#arrowShape)"></rect>
```

In my research I noticed that I only needed to add "window.location.search" in to that "path" variable and everything started to work also in "search" page. BUT 100% working version needed also some js logic, because I noticed that if your url is like "http ://example.com/en/?"

Internet Explorer will return "?" from "window.location.search". Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera will return just "" which is not enough to that svg mask to work.

```
$scope.path = '';
var tmp = $window.location.search;
if(tmp !== "") {
   $scope.path = tmp;
}
else if(/\?$/.test($window.location.href)) {
   $scope.path = '?';
}
```

After this svg mask started working consistently. (As a sidenote I have html5mode turned off.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix (in svg.js and dist files): https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/325

```
URL = Snap.url = function (url) {
    // return "url('#" + url + "')";
    return "url('" + window.location.pathname + "#" + url + "')";
};
```