# SVG Clip-Path not working on Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

I have a simple animation that fills an svg from the bottom up and then fades out. The filling is done using a `clipPath` along with using a `path` with a `stroke-dasharray` & `stroke-dashoffset`.

The problem is the `clipPath` seems to be completely ignored on Safari. I've seen many other examples and questions answered that make use of the `clip-path` property in Safari successfully, but not in this case.

Any ideas of what specifically is stopping Safari from rendering this correctly?

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7qzf4c4j/1/

```css
.pen {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#logoclip);
  clip-path: url(#logoclip);
  stroke-dasharray: 60 60;
  stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  -webkit-animation: fill-logo 2.7s infinite linear;
  animation: fill-logo 2.7s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes fill-logo {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="-305 397.9 70 60.1" enable-background="new -305 397.9 70 60.1">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="logoclip">
      <path d="m-270 397.9c-22.9 11.5-35 25.4-35 40.3 0 5.9 1.8 10.9 5.3 14.4 3.4 3.5 11-3.7 2.7-2.3 4.2-5.6 4.2-9.1v-8.6c0-1-.3-2.1-.9-3-1 .5-2 .8-2.9.8-1.4 0-2.4-.8-2.4-1.8 0-1 .9-1.7 2.3-1.7 1.2 0 2.3.6 3.2 1.7.3-.2.6-.4.9-.6-1.5-1.4-2.3-2.9-2.3-4.1 0-1.1.7-1.8 1.7-1.8.4 0 .8.2 1.2.5.3-.3.7-.5 2.7-2.3 4.1.3.2.6.4.9.6.9-1.1 2.1-1.7 3.2-1.7 1.3 0 2.3.7 2.3 1.7 0 1-1 1.8-2.4 1.8-1 0-1.9-.3-2.9-.8-.6.9-.9 2-.9 3v8.6c0 7.2 6.7 12.8 15.2 12.8 5.6 0 10.3-1.9 13.7-5.4 3.4-3.5 5.3-8.5 5.3-14.4 0-14.8-12.1-28.8-35-40.3"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <path class="pen" d="m-270,458 l0,-60.1" stroke="black" stroke-width="100" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben, my suggestion probably looks funny, but remove `-webkit-clip-path:url(#logoclip);` from your `.pen`. Keep `clip-path:url(#logoclip);` (without `-webkit-`) only.

In my Safari 10.1.1 it does the trick.

Comment: Funnily enough, that does fix it in the fiddle, but not on the site I'm using it on, even though I've replicated it as close as possible. I'll keep digging, now that I know it is possible it's just finding out what's preventing it...

Comment: I've figured out the other problem and will post an answer but your answer does indeed solve a major issue (can anyone shed some light on why this is?) It may be worth noting that specifying `webkit-clip-path: none;` may help to prevent anything adding the prefix automatically and breaking (as was happening on my project)

Answer (score 2):

Kosh pointed out the main issue with this code but another thing that gave me a major headache was the project I'm working on has a `base` tag which is treated differently in Safari when referencing urls for clip-paths.

This SO question covers it well: [Using base tag on a page that contains SVG marker elements fails to render marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259032/using-base-tag-on-a-page-that-contains-svg-marker-elements-fails-to-render-marke)

As a reference the way I fixed this was to use an existing Angular.js directive already encapsulating the svg to watch the location and update the url between navigations, like this:

```js
// manually replace url of svg to circumvent base href
var pen = element.find('.pen')[0];
scope.$watch(function() {
  return location.href;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  pen.style.clipPath = 'url('+newVal+'#logoclip)';
});
```

The output then becomes something like this:

```css
clip-path: url(http://localhost:3000/page#logoclip);
```

**EDIT:** I also thought that maybe the reason `-webkit-clip-path` wasn't working was because it required a full path, but I tried setting the property using the code above and it *still* doesn't render the clip-path properly. I assume this is a bug specifically with `-webkit-clip-path` although if anyone has any info I'd be interested in knowing why this happens.