# Why are my SVG rating stars invisible on Heroku, but show up on my localhost?

Tags: html, css, svg, heroku, mean-stack

I have built an Angular 5 review application (MEAN stack).  I implemented the angular-star-rating package, so users can leave a star rating in their reviews in the application.

When I run my app locally, it works great.  I can see the stars without issue!

I deployed my app to Heroku, and the stars are invisible.  If I inspect the element, and click on where the stars should be, the element responds.  So it seems that the stars are still reacting to user activity, but again, are invisible.

I have been searching different questions and experimenting with what could be going wrong, but have not been able to find a solution to this issue.  Is Heroku unable to display SVG tags?

I don't think it's a problem with the configuration of the package.  I thought it could be an issue with the xlink tags one must include, as I noticed others having display issues when they weren't included.  But the xlink tags are included.  Code below:

```
<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">


    <defs>

        <symbol id="star-empty" viewBox="0 0 34 32">
            <title>star-empty</title>
            <path class="path-star-empty"
                  d="M33.412 12.395l-11.842-1.021-4.628-10.904-4.628 10.92-11.842 1.005 8.993 7.791-2.701 11.579 10.179-6.144 10.179 6.144-2.685-11.579 8.976-7.791zM16.941 22.541l-6.193 3.739 1.647-7.049-5.468-4.744 7.214-0.626 2.8-6.638 2.816 6.654 7.214 0.626-5.468 4.744 1.647 7.049-6.209-3.755z"/>
        </symbol>

        <symbol id="star-half" viewBox="0 0 34 32">
            <title>star-half</title>
            <path class="path-star-half"
                  d="M 33.412,12.395 21.57,11.374 16.942,0.47 12.314,11.39 0.472,12.395 9.465,20.186 6.764,31.765 16.943,25.621 27.122,31.765 24.437,20.186 33.413,12.395 Z M 16.941,22.541 c 0,0 -0.297971,-14.6455833 0,-15.318 l 2.816,6.654 7.214,0.626 -5.468,4.744 1.647,7.049 z"/>
        </symbol>

        <symbol id="star-filled" viewBox="0 0 34 32">
            <title>star-filled</title>
            <path class="path-star-filled"
                  d="M16.941 25.621l10.179 6.144-2.701-11.579 8.993-7.791-11.842-1.005-4.628-10.92-4.628 10.92-11.842 1.005 8.993 7.791-2.701 11.579z"/>
        </symbol>

    </defs>
</svg>
```

This code is in an svg file I serve from my assets, as directed by the implementation instructions, found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-star-rating

Any ideas are much appreciated.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Check the Net tab of your browser dev tools. Are you seeing any errors loading those files?  Is your page using angular routing?  If so, it might be adding a `<base>` element that is affecting relative URL resolution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259032/using-base-tag-on-a-page-that-contains-svg-marker-elements-fails-to-render-marke

Comment: Also check the the web server is serving the files with the correct `Content-type`  (MIME type) header. It should be `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  When I check the network tab, it shows a 304 status for the svg.  However, when I check the content-type, it says text/html.  I'm not sure why that is.  Do you think this could be pointing towards the issue?

Comment: The 304 response just means the requested file hasn't changed since you last fetched it.  Presumably there was an earlier fetch of the SVG file that you may have missed.  Look for that one.

Comment: Thanks @PaulLeBeau.  Strangely, it still says text/html even with a 200, visiting the site on different browsers with cache cleared.

Comment: It serves svg in localhost, but not on Heroku.  Is this a cross origin issue?  Shouldn't node serve svg files out of the box, if the xlinks are specified correctly?

Comment: Then it sounds like your server is not configured correctly. It needs to serve the SVG files with a content type of `image/svg+xml` otherwise browsers will not treat the file as an SVG.  I'm not familiar enough with Heroku to be able to tell you exactly what you need to do, sorry. You'll have to look into that yourself.

Comment: Ok @PaulLeBeau thank you for your help.  I appreciate it.  So you think that this is an issue with how Node is configured with Heroku?

Comment: If SVG files (ie. `.svg`) are being returned with a `Content-type: text/html` header, as you suggest, then there is definitely a configuration issue with your server.