# svg is not properly rendering when navigate route in safari, angular

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, safari

My problem is that SVG is not rendering properly when url has some route like 'localhost/hello' in Safari

In Chrome, Working fine.

You can compare this problem using both browser ( Chrome, Safari ) in your computer using my example

example)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruscfd

How to solve this problem using general approach which make this rendering issue work properly in both browser??

Plz help.

In Safari
[image: In Safari]

In Chrome
[image: In Chrome]

Comment: there's a <base href="/"> in the head. Chrome ignores it, safari doesn't. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259032/using-base-tag-on-a-page-that-contains-svg-marker-elements-fails-to-render-marke for workarounds

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you. Thank you very much you saved my life!...