# Reference SVG effect without using url() function

Tags: javascript, html, svg

We are using Svelte/Sapper front-end with client-side routing. When user is navigating between different pages, SVGs on the page sometimes glitch-out. Example:

[image]

(SVG source in the end of the question)

This glitching is caused by using HTML `<base>` tag and referencing linear gradient effect with CSS `url()` function. This results in invalid URL (base + element id) inside SVG and effect will not be applied.

Related issues to my problem:

- [SVG Showing up as a black box in Safari (Mobile / Desktop)](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3450)
- [Using base tag on a page that contains SVG marker elements fails to render marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259032/using-base-tag-on-a-page-that-contains-svg-marker-elements-fails-to-render-marke/18265336#18265336)
- [iOS - Linear Gradients showing as Black](https://github.com/airbnb/visx/issues/317)
- [SVGs turn to black in Safari during transformations, akin to a bug with  tag](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/899)
- [SVG path fill rendering can break after window.history.pushState](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652991)
- [SVG url() doesn't work under  in Safari and Firefox](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/360)

My question is then: **Can I reference effect such as `<linearGradient>` without relaying on `url()` function to avoid this issue entirely?**

---

#### Hacky solution

I solved this issue by listening to end of animation event and then adding and in `setTimeout` removing `display: inline-block;` on `<svg>` element. This is forcing browser to re-render it and fixes glitch after each animation. This is obviously hacky solution with lot of technical debt. I will post different answer with solution if I find different/better way of solving this.

---

SVG icon source:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: currentColor;" class="w-8 h-8" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <defs>
    <path id="a" d="M12 10.3L2.4 1v22l9.6-9.2 1.8-1.8 5.4-5.2v10.5l-3.7-3.5-1.8 1.7 7.9 7.6V1L12 10.3zm-7.1 6.9V6.8l5.4 5.2-5.4 5.2z">
    </path>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="b">
    <use href="#a" overflow="visible"></use>
  </clipPath>
  <g clip-path="url(#b)">
    <linearGradient id="c" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-732.18" y1="294.75" x2="-731.55" y2="294.75" gradientTransform="scale(47.46 -47.46) rotate(45 -9.66 1030.9)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#201351"></stop>
      <stop offset=".25" stop-color="#201351"></stop>
      <stop offset=".39" stop-color="#620f3c"></stop>
      <stop offset=".53" stop-color="#990b2a"></stop>
      <stop offset=".65" stop-color="#c1081e"></stop>
      <stop offset=".74" stop-color="#d90716"></stop>
      <stop offset=".8" stop-color="#e20613"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#e20613"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#c)" d="M-8.6 12L12-8.6 32.6 12 12 32.6z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I suspect you'll have to use absolute URIs inside the `url()` functions.

Comment: I cant. I have client-side routing and URL address in the browser is changing constantly.

Comment: This is just an issue with Safari these days isn't it? If so, download its source code and fix the bug would seem to be your only option here if you can't use absolute URLs

Comment: I reproduced it in: Chrome, Firefox, Safari

Comment: Not sure what you're doing then. Can you produce a [mcve] i.e. something we can directly run?

Comment: For instance I see a gradient [with this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/1337e9d398f546d6ae30471bbce94595?version=3.9.1) in Firefox.

Comment: You can directly embed the SVG into your `url` method using `data('image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,.......#id')`.

Comment: I am not able to make minimal reproducible example. I can however reproduce it with 100% success in our application but when I try to reproduce it outside the app i can't. When I copy SVG code and paste it in different part of DOM tree then it sometimes starts to work for new copy and also for original SVG element.

For minimal reproduction, I tried animating it, pushing to history, toggling in with display style but nothing works. In our app it glitches when app is pushing to history and screen animation in done.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same id value in the same document? I suspect that's your problem and not the URL at all.

Comment: I pasted multiple instances of this SVG file on the page and issue is not occurring (so multiple ids is not the issue). It must be something specific related to: base tag, pushing to history and animating the page.

Comment: Small debuging note: When i change display CSS property to anything and then revert it, it fixes that glitch. Maybe it's some rendering issue that is persistent trough multiple browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution would be to reference all icons from one [SVG sprite file](https://w3bits.com/svg-sprites/) at a static address.

For example `https://example.com/assets/sprite.svg` would quote the icon markup in `<symbol>` elements:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- use the viewBox from your icon <svg> element -->
    <symbol id="unique-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <!-- quote everything inside your icon <svg> element -->
    </symbol>
    <!-- more icons -->
</svg>
```

and icon usage would look like this:

```
 <svg><use xlink:href="https://example.com/assets/sprite.svg#unique-icon></svg>`.
```

Note you can still apply styles to that `<use>` element, which will be inherited by the icon markup inside the shadow DOM.

Comment: This solution would require some changes in our icon system and could be very time consuming. I will discuss this solution with my team.

Comment: There are CI solutions for this. For example combine [svg-sprite](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite) with a task runner like gulp or grunt or [iconizr](https://github.com/jkphl/node-iconizr), or use a webpack plugin.